# log4j logs are getting written to catalina.out file

Tags: java, tomcat

My log4j logs are getting written to my catalina.out file. I have no idea where these messages are coming from, as I don't have them anywhere in my application code. This is filling up my catalina file. How do I fix this? I don't know where to even look for these messages to stop them from landing in catalina.out file. Please suggest.

Here is my logging.properties file -

```
 handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, 2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, 3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, 4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
.handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = catalina.

2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = localhost.

3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = manager.

4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = host-manager.

java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = FINE
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].handlers = 2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager].handlers = 3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/host-manager].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/host-manager].handlers = 4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler
```

Comment: AFAIK if you route to stdout it will get written to catalina.out

Comment: Share your log4j.properties file

Comment: @Aditya - How do I share it? Can I attach it?

Comment: Please provide your log4j configuration. It might possible that logs are coming from any associated jar file. If they are debug log and not useful than rise the level to error/fatal for those logs

Comment: How do I provide the configuration? I don't know how to attach it.

Answer (score 5):

You should create a `log4j.properties` file in your project and redirect your root log4j logger to a non-console appender. RollingFileAppender, for instance, is the best candidate for this.

For example:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, main

log4j.appender.main=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.main.File=main.log
```

Comment: Should this be in logging.properties in conf, or my log4j.xml in WEB-INF/classes?

Comment: No, `logging.properties` is a configuration of `java.util.logging.*`, which has no relation to `log4j`. And yes, the default location of `log4j.properties` should be at `WEB-INF/classes` in your case.

Comment: Ok. So should I be modifying logging.properties or log4j.properties?

Comment: For log4j - `log4j.properties`. For java.util.logging - `logging.properties`